# iPhone shows up as offline in Google location sharing

Tags: iphone, sharing, google, geolocation

I have an iPhone and want to share my live location using Google Maps. I can find my friends using Android and they can see one another, but somehow they cannot see my location. I only show up as offline on their phones. In Google Maps it says my location are being shared and I have enabled all required settings.

Anyone else who has experienced the same? Any suggestions for solutions?